# Building function to determine what denomination a number is

Tags: swift, function, io, double

I am trying to build a function that takes a number at determines what denomination it is, for example is it in the thousands, millions, billions, etc.

Below is what I have written but it only works some of the time. For example when the number is ten million my functions thinks it is in the thousands, which I can't understand because there clearly are more than 6 digits in ten million.

My code:

```
func configureDenominationLabel() {

let roundedDouble = round(veryLargeNumber)

let roundedDoubleInTextForm = String(roundedDouble)

switch roundedDoubleInTextForm.count {
case 0...3:
    denominationsLabel.text = ""
case 4...6:
    denominationsLabel.text = "Thousand"
case 7...9:
    denominationsLabel.text = "Million"
case 10...12:
    denominationsLabel.text = "Billion"
case 13...15:
    denominationsLabel.text = "Trillion"
default:
    denominationsLabel.text = ""
}
}
```

Comment: What is `textNPV` and where does it come from? Why is `roundedDoubleInTextForm` computed but not used? – Is this your real code? Did you try to *debug* it?

Comment: Sorry about that I copied and pasted my code and made some changes but didn't adjust everything after the changes. I've updated it and it's consistent.

Comment: *Debug* your problem. Start with printing the values of `roundedDoubleInTextForm` and `roundedDoubleInTextForm.count` ...

Comment: @MartinR thank you. I should have been able to do that myself. The problem was I didn't account for the decimal point.

Answer (score -1):

I am not convinced that using the `count` method on string is the best way to do this. If you want your code to look better, you can try something like this:

```
extension Double {

    var thousands: Double { return self * pow(10, 3) }
    var millions: Double { return self * pow(10, 6) }
    var billions: Double { return self * pow(10, 9) }
    var trillions: Double { return self * pow(10, 12) }
    ...

}

...

if veryLargeNumber < 1.thousands {
    denominationsLabel.text = ""
} else if veryLargeNumber < 1000.thousands {
    denominationsLabel.text = "Thousands"
} else if veryLargeNumber < 1000.millions {
    denominationsLabel.text = "Millions"
} else if veryLargeNumber < 1000.billions {
    denominationsLabel.text = "Billions"
} else if veryLargeNumber < 1000.trillions {
    denominationsLabel.text = "Trillions"
} else {
    denominationsLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `10^3` does not evaluate to 1000?

Comment: You're right, I forgot, it's the bit-wise XOR I think. You can use `pow(10, 3)` or create a custom operator with `**`